# Python typeerrorfloatrequiredline.20

Tags: python, arrays

```
#Python program when involved with maths
import math

def areaOfcircle(x):
#Calculate the area
    area=(math.pi)*math.pow(x,2)
    print(area,"is the area of your circle")
#Input used to find x
areaOfcircle(int(input("What is the radius of your circle?")))

def areaOftriangle(b,h):
    area=(b+h)/2
    print(area,"is the area of your triangle")

areaOftriangle(int(input("What is the base of your triangle")),int(input("What is the hight of your triangle")))

def areaOfsquare(x):
    area=math.pow(x,2)
    print(area,"is the area of your square")

areaOfsquare("What is the length of your square?")

flag="f"
while flag=="f":
    shape=input("Which of the following shapes, Circle, Triangle or Square do you want to calculate the area of: ")
    if shape=="Triangle" or "triangle":
        area=areaOftriangle
        print(area)

elif shape=="Square" or "square":
    area=areaOfsqaure
    print(area)

elif shape=="Circle" or "circle":
    area=areaOfcircle(x)
    print(area)
```

Comment: You have the error on when reading the `areaOfsquare` ... you need to ask for input but you are not doing that.

Comment: Is there a question?

Answer (score 0):

Im feeling in the mood today. I fixed your code to the desired functionality you require. :)
Mainly, you have multiple errors.
1) indentation error with your `elif`s.
2) argument passing error with `area=areaOfcircle(x)`.
3) `areaOfsquare("What is the length of your square?")` is trying to pass a string and calculate the string.
4) Design-wise, you should be asking user input for shape first before asking for measurements.
5) `if shape=="Triangle" or "triangle":` should be changed to `if shape.lower() == 'triangle':`

```
import math

def areaOfcircle(x):
    area=(math.pi)*math.pow(x,2)
    print(area,"is the area of your circle")

def areaOftriangle(b,h):
    area=(b+h)/2
    print(area,"is the area of your triangle")

def areaOfsquare(x):
    area=math.pow(x,2)
    print(area,"is the area of your square")



flag="f"
while flag=="f":
    shape=input("Which of the following shapes, Circle, Triangle or Square do you want to calculate the area of: ")
    if shape.lower() == "triangle":
        areaOftriangle(float(input("What is the base of your triangle? ")),float(input("What is the height of your triangle? ")))
        break

    elif shape.lower() == "square":
        areaOfsquare(float(input("What is the length of your square? ")))
        break

    elif shape.lower() == "circle":
        area=areaOfcircle(float(input("What is the radius of your circle? ")))
        break
    else:
        print('No such shape, please try again')
```

Comment: What is the `flag` declaration get you if you just compare it to your own declaration, aside from getting you into an infinite loop? I understand the questioner did so, but you're not quite into a sensible state yet. I may be missing something.

Comment: @TheHerk The `flag` declaration does not matter much because its a `True`-y value. I have no clue why questioner does not want to do a `while True:` loop. I simply fixed all the bugs in the code to achieve the desired functionality. The infinite loop is broken by the `break`